# How to implement an async sequential worker in C#

Tags: c#, .net, task, producer-consumer, worker

In C# .Net 4, I want to implement an async sequential worker, that queues and performs Actions one by one. However two or more sequential workers can run concurrently and independent from each other.
What would be the best implementation regarding performance and resource usage?! (I know that a producer-consumer pattern would be suitable for this but how to implement it?!)

Below I put the code of the empty class and then a naive implementation for it.

```
public class SequentialWorker
{
    public void DoAsync(Action action1)
    {
        // queue and run action1 after previous actions, on a seperate thread
    }
}
```

Naive implementation:

```
public class SequentialWorker
{
    private Task task;
    private readonly Queue<Action> actions = new Queue<Action>();

    public void DoAsync(Action action1)
    {
        lock (actions)
        {
            actions.Enqueue(action1);
            if (task == null || task.IsCompleted) // if completed or not created, create a new task
            {
                task = Task.Factory.StartNew(DoActions);
            }
        }
    }

    private void DoActions()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Action action;
                lock (actions)
                {
                    if (!actions.Any())
                        return;
                    action = actions.Dequeue();
                }

                action();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //handle e
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not actually an answer, but [ReaderWriterLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock(v=vs.110).aspx) can be helpful in your scenario.

Comment: Or you could save yourself a lot of work and use [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I tested TPL Dataflow for this purpose. The implementation was simpler than mine, I liked that. However it was not faster in comparison to Naive code (I created a test with multiple workers doing long running floating point tasks, and the running times were almost the same) @ibebbs

Comment: @vadim thanks, but I don't know how to use it for my purpose!